# TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord

Пишу музыкального дискорд бота для своего сервера, но при запуске песни в консоли выходит ошибка

```
if (results.items.length < 1) return resolve([])
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Ошибка происходит в плагине discord-player вот код самого плагина:

```
            ytsr(query, (err, results) => {
                if (results.items.length < 1) return resolve([])
                if (err) return resolve([])
                const resultsVideo = results.items.filter((i) => i.type === 'video')
                resolve(allResults ? resultsVideo.map((r) => new Track(r, null, null)) : [new Track(resultsVideo[0], null, null)])
            })
```

Может кто пользовался этим плагином? Помогите пожалуйста!!!!

Comment: а вы эту `ytsr` как-то вызываете?

Comment: @nörbörnën точно не знаю код не мой. Исходник скачал, проверил и под себя переделываю. Могу ссылку на исходник скинуть.

Comment: лучше обновите библиотеки так как , судя по https://github.com/Androz2091/discord-player/blob/56729a5b973ee1fc04b52fea456fa6bad14d1a09/src/Player.js#L206, у вас там что-то старенькое

Comment: @nörbörnën Спасибо. Сейчас проверю)

Comment: в том коде, что я вижу, такое исключение обработалось бы корректно

Comment: @nörbörnën Не работает :( обновил плагин изменений в нем не увидел. Код не работает. Выдает такую же ошибку.

Comment: и какая версия discord-player у тебя теперь установлена?

Comment: @nörbörnën 3.0.0-beta.1

Comment: ну, скинь ссылку на исходник

Comment: @nörbörnën https://github.com/ZerioDev/Music-bot

Comment: посмотрел. в общем, в package.json стоит ссылка на "discord-player": "github:Androz2091/discord-player#develop", что соответствует версии `2.3.0` в которой действительно есть тот код, что показан у тебя в сообщении. не знаю откуда ты взял  3.0.0-beta.1, скорее всего это - глобально установленная библиотека. рекомендация: в репе https://github.com/ZerioDev/Music-bot в package.json нужно проставить зависимость от современной версии библиотеки discord-player (я сделал это так `yarn add discord-player`)